# Зачем BufferedInputStream, если InputStream предоставляет read с буфером

Tags: java, поток-ввода

Зачем понадобилось включать в систему ввода-вывода Java обертку `BufferedInputStream`, если все реализации интерфейса `InputStream` по умолчанию содержат метод `read(byte b[])`, в котором для чтения из потока используется буфер?

Для примера, написал программу, которая копирует видеофайл ~100 мб из одного файла в другой.

1. Реализация с использованием `BufferedInputStream`:

   ```
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

       BufferedInputStream fis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/tests/1.mp4"));
       BufferedOutputStream fos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/tests/2.mp4"));

       int b=fis.read();
       while (b!=-1){
           fos.write(b);
           b=fis.read();
       }
       fos.flush();        
   }
   ```
2. Реализация с использованием метода `read(byte b[])`

   ```
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:/tests/1.mp4");
       FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/tests/2.mp4");

       byte[] buff=new byte[4096];
       int bytes=fis.read(buff);

       while(bytes!=-1){
           fos.write(buff, 0, bytes);
           bytes=fis.read(buff);
       }           
   }
   ```

Реализация с использованием класса `BufferedInputStream` работает примерно в 10 раз медленнее

Comment: как вы посчитали время?

Comment: Ответ прост: время выполнения. https://habr.com/post/132374/

Comment: BufferedReader читает поток "наперед" и сохраняет то, что прочитал.Последующие вызовы, читают не из файла, а из буфера.

Comment: @michael_best при использовании `read(byte b[])` файл копируется мгновенно, при использовании же `BufferedInputStream` приходится ждать секунд 10-15

Comment: Тест неправильный. Один раз вы читаете весь файл целиком, а второй раз байт за байтом.

Comment: @aleshka-batman почему это целиком/байт за байтом? В первом случае буферизация с использованием массива, во втором - с использованием метода `read` специального оптимизированного класса

Comment: Еще раз, с чего вы взяли что BufferedInputStream работает медленнее чем системный вызов read из FileInputStream? Вы составляли бечмарки, меряли скорость выполнения, может еще есть процентное соотношение из JProfiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте сравнить скорость обработки с буферизацией и считыванием массива:

```
BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/tests/1.mp4"));
BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/tests/2.mp4"));
byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
int bytes = fis.read(buff);
while (bytes != -1) {
    fos.write(buff, 0, bytes);
    bytes = fis.read(buff);
}
fos.flush();
```

Полагаю, что скорость обработки будет сравнима со скоростью без буферизации, а может, даже быстрее, за счет другого размера буфера.

### Почему первый пример работает медленно

Считывание/запись массива байтов из локального файла — очень быстрая операция. В лучше случае `BufferedInputStream` (`BufferedOutputStream`) не повлияет на производительность существенным образом, в худшем — производительность упадет из-за различных накладных расходов.

В вашем случае байты (~ 10^8) после считывания из буфера обрабатываются по одному, что сильно увеличивает накладные расходы:

- для каждого байта вызываются методы `read` и `write` — вызовы методов не бесплатны;
- хуже того, оба метода синхронизированные (`synchronized`) и при каждом вызове виртуальная машина выполняет переключение контекста/блокировку;
- в самих методах есть разнообразные проверки (открыт ли входной/выходной поток, закончился ли буфер и т.п.), которые также отнимают время.

Я полагаю, что основную нагрузку создает синхронизация. Можете для эксперимента добавить синхронизированные методы в вариант с `FileInputStream`

```
    while (bytes != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
            write(read(buff[i]));
        }
        fos.write(buff, 0, bytes);
        bytes = fis.read(buff);
    }
}

static int count = 0;

public static synchronized void write(int b) {
    //неважно
    count += b;
}

public static synchronized int read(int b) {
    return count + b;
}
```

### Зачем `BufferedInputStream`

Буферизированные потоки нужны чтобы не писать буферизацию самому. Также они позволяют отделить логику программы от настроек буферизации. `BufferedInputStream` особенно удобен если:

1. Используется алгоритм, который обрабатывает байты последовательно. В этом случае можно упростить код, доверив буферизацию встроенному классу.
2. Сам поток используется в качестве аргумента для класса-чтеца.

   Например, `BufferedInputStream` можно передать в качестве аргумента `Scanner`:

   ```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("input")));
   ```

   После этого через `Scanner` можно будет работать с данными построчно, а `BufferedInputStream` сэкономит на обращениях к файловой системе.
3. Используются специфичные методы.

   Методы [`InputStream.mark`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark-int-) и [`InputStream.reset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset--), как правило, недоступны в небуферизированных потоках. Соответственно, если потребуется откатывать состояние потока, то использовать `FileInputStream` не получится.

На примере с копированием файла преимущества увидеть сложно. С другой стороны, для копирования файла целесообразнее использовать [встроенные методы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-), а не потоки.